# Showing a set is not compact by describing an open cover that doesn't have a finite subcover

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

I would like to prove that the following set is not compact by stating an open cover for it that has no finite subcover.

> $E=\{x\in\mathbb{Q}:0\leq x\leq2\}$

I'm having trouble thinking of one. A hint would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: Can you do it with $\{x\in\Bbb Q:0\le x\le\sqrt2\}$? If so, you can also do it with $E$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** Open intervals in $\Bbb Q$ need not be defined by rational endpoints.